# Appsheet use image url as image from second table

Tags: google-appsheet

I am trying to use the url for the image reference on my app sheet using Virtual Column but the problem is it wont detect as Image but instead as List

[image]

by the way, image links are listed on the Sheet2

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a [mcve]  (error messages should be added as text, not as images, show a sample spreadsheet some sample URLs and the steps you followed to add the virtual column)

Answer (score 0):

If you're storing that value inside a separate table, just as a place to store the variable, you've got the right idea. You just need to extract the first value out of your list.

The following syntax creates a list of all the values in a column for a table: `Table[Column]`

This tells the system to go to the table ***Table*** and pull every value in the column ***Column***, creating a list of the values (including the blanks, not counting blanks past the last row in the sheet of course).

To get the first value out of that list: `index(table[column], 1)`